# double precision lost on cgal

Tags: cgal

I am retrieving the coordinates x,y,z from a `xyz` file to compute a delaunay. The values have double precision.

If I print or save the values of a point, x and y have no longer double precision, but the z does. I've debugged the program and if I add a watch expression as `*(double*)<address of the x>` I get the original, correct `double` value.

I've tried casting `point().x()` to `*(double*)` but of course `x()` returns a `double`, not a `double*`. Somehow, the precision is lost when retrieved.

Any clue?

I am using

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Projection_traits_xy_3<K>  Gt;

typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<Gt> Vb;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_mesh_face_base_2<Gt> Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb, Fb> Tds;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<Gt, Tds> CDT;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just had to change the precision of the streams.

```
outstream << std::fixed << setprecision(4) ;
```